# Intel pstate, turbo always on CPU temp is 60 and without only ~43

Tags: power-management, intel, cpu

I have a problem with pState on my Thinkpad L450 with Intel 5200U (broadwell) + SSD.

When I use pstate, the turbo mode is nearly always turned ON and my CPU fan is also always ON because CPU temp is about 60°C.

While using acpi cpufreq in ondemand mode, my CPU frequency is around 0.50 to 2.1 GHz without turbo. As a result, my CPU temperature is only 40-45°C which drives to less energy consumption and 4+ hours of battery life or 5.5+ hours (rarely 6+) when frequency is locked to 0.5 Ghz.

However, while using pstate, battery life has a maximum of 4 hours even in powersave mode.

More info:

1. I have stopped using tlp, no big difference with or without it
2. PowerTop reports nearly everything is "Bad" (I hate autosuspends, but that does not change the huge difference between pstate and acpi)

Some more details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid

Linux version 3.19.0-26-generic (buildd@lcy01-12) 
(gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) ) 
#28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:32 UTC 2015
```

Any idea what is happening? In theory the pstate is intelligent enough to manager power correctly, but an always turbo ON state with always 2.2+ GHz is not a very intelligent solution to manager power.